# Returning function values to determine what will be printed

Tags: python

I will make a function with parameter "n". I want a function to return "n" as either 0 or 1. If 0, then the user input will be considered less than or equal to 0. If 1, then the user input will be considered greater than 0.

This is what I have so far and I'm not sure how to correct my mistakes.

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Enter a value: "))
    integer(n) 
def integer(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return n*0
    elif n > 0:
        return n*0 + 1
def integer(n=0):
    print("That value is less than or equal to 0")
def integer(n=1):
    print("That value is greater than 0")
main()
```

Comment: why not return a boolean instead of 1 or 0?

Comment: Does this always output "That value is greater than 0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have overridden your definition of integer. The following script works fine. Also, `n*0` is unnecessary because it always evaluates to 0.

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Enter a value: "))
    fb=integer(n)
    if fb == 0:
        print("That value is less than or equal to 0")
    else:
        print("That value is greater than 0")
def integer(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    elif n > 0:
        return 1

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it's much shorter:

```
def main():
    d = {0:'That value is less than or equal to 0',1:"That value is greater than 0"}
    n = int(input("Enter a value: "))
    fb=integer(n)
    print(d[fb])
def integer(n):
    return 0 if n <= 0 else 1

main()
```

I just simply create a dictionary

Comment: The entire thing can be condensed into one line with functions defined by using `lambda` if you really want... But it loses clarity.